# Asp.net MVC Dynamic String Values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to implement an inventory management system. There are types of inventories and there are properties need to be asked, based on inventory type.

IE: If inventory type is noteBook, i need to get "Processor" or if inventory type is monitor, i need to get "Inch" value.

It should be good if there will be input types for my parameters but i could not find any good tutorial.

I have do lots of search i could not find helpfull documents.

Here is my models.

```
public class PcmInventoryType : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PcmInventoryParameter> RelatedParameters { get; set; }
}

public class PcmInventoryParameter : BaseModel
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public int PcmInventoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual PcmInventoryType PcmInventoryType { get; set; }
}

public class PcmInventory : BaseModel
{
    public int PcmInventoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual PcmInventoryType PcmInventoryType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PcmInventoryParameterValue> PcmInventoryParameterValues { get; set; }
}

public class PcmInventoryParameterValue : BaseModel
{
    public int PcmInventoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual PcmInventory PcmInventory { get; set; }

    public int PcmInventoryParameterId { get; set; }
    public virtual PcmInventoryParameter PcmInventoryParameter { get; set; }

    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to keep my inventory types in `PcmInventoryType` and the parameters (should be in a form when i  want to create new inventory) in `PcmInventoryParameter`.

How can i create a dynamic form while adding an new `PcmInventory`. I searched in stackoverflow, and i have found that i need to use `EditorTemplate`.

But i cant figure out with my models.

Regards.

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with? Creating a view model to represent what you want to edit or creating the view? (using an `EditorTemplate` or not is not really relevant.